# Variable gets a value as if the shift command had not been executed

Tags: arduino, esp32

This is my simple program in the infinite loop that only measures the voltage from the mains and saves the value in the variable ulp_vars.pin2.val. The problem is that at some undefined intervals but certainly under one second this variable gets a value as if the shift command had not been executed. This is a simplified example from the HULP library, and in that original example, I didn't notice anything like this happening. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
#include "hulp_arduino.h"

#define PIN_ADC_PIN2    GPIO_NUM_34

#define PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_SHIFT 3

RTC_DATA_ATTR struct {
  ulp_var_t pin2;
} ulp_vars;

void ulp_init()
{
  enum {
    LBL_PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_LOOP,
    LBL_LOOP,
  };

  const ulp_insn_t program[] = {

    M_LABEL(LBL_LOOP),
    I_STAGE_RST(),//
    I_MOVI(R0, 0),//These are just attempts to solve the problem.
    I_MOVI(R1, 0),//
    I_MOVI(R2, 0),//
    I_MOVI(R3, 0),
    M_LABEL(LBL_PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_LOOP),
    I_ANALOG_READ(R1, PIN_ADC_PIN2),
    I_ADDR(R0, R0, R1),
    I_STAGE_INC(1),
    M_BSLT(LBL_PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_LOOP, (1 << PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_SHIFT)),
    I_RSHI(R0, R0, PIN2_OVERSAMPLE_SHIFT),
    I_MOVI(R3, 0),
    I_PUT(R0, R3, ulp_vars.pin2),
    I_GPIO_SET(GPIO_NUM_14, 1),//This produces 1.43 uS pulse
    I_GPIO_SET(GPIO_NUM_14, 0),// for test, nothing else !
    I_DELAY(10),
    I_BXI(LBL_LOOP),

  };
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_configure_pin(GPIO_NUM_14, RTC_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_ONLY, GPIO_FLOATING, 1));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_configure_analog_pin(PIN_ADC_PIN2, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11, ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12));
  //ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_ulp_load(program, sizeof(program), 1000UL * ULP_WAKEUP_INTERVAL_MS, 0));
  size_t size = sizeof(program) / sizeof(ulp_insn_t);
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ulp_process_macros_and_load(0, program, &size));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_ulp_run(0));
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (hulp_is_deep_sleep_wakeup())
  {
    Serial.print("Wakeup !");
  }
  else
  {
    ulp_init();
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(ulp_vars.pin2.val);
}
```

Comment: This is a wild guess but perhaps you need to declare `ulp_vars` as `volatile`?

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the solution, although that part of the RTC _RAM memory is only available for ULP, and since this is an assembler program, there is no allocation of variables. I was thinking that maybe some of the sleep registers SENS_ULP_CP_SLEEP_CYCn_REG were not adequately deleted at startup or while calling the ULP program.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. If you need an infinite loop in the ULP program at the beginning of the program add:
`I_WR_REG_BIT (RTC_CNTL_STATE0_REG, RTC_CNTL_ULP_CP_SLP_TIMER_EN, 0)`

and so you forbade the influence of the start timer on the flow of the program!